# VBA code to sum values and insert them in new file in specific format? (Pivot table or no?)

Tags: vba

I have a variety of folders with the same format and different numbers. EX:

```
OperatingUnit  "NO NAME"       GEP  NEP


      1         Disability     50   20
      2         MSL            20   2
      3         Aviation       5    6
      1         Disability     10   10
      3         Aviation       6    20
```

The files have 2 empty rows between the column header and the actual data (as displayed above). I believe I have a working code to loop through all the files so right now I'm just working on the macro the loop will have to call.

What I want, is to put the data in a new file (which I have already named and put the column headers) with the following values underneath them:

```
RptLOB      ECMAccount  Amount
Disability  GEP         60      (SUM of the GEP values where the "NO NAME" column = Disability)
Disability  NEP         30      (same as top but NEP values)
MSL         GEP         20
MSL         NEP         2
Aviation    GEP         11
Aviation    NEP         26
```

I'm not quite sure if I will need to create a pivot table but because there are those 2 empty cells between the header and the data, it won't let me even if I try it manually.  What's a good way of approaching this through VBA?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `SUMIFS` ?

Comment: @enderland In the new file with the `RptLOB  ECMAccount  Amount` columns, there is absolutely no data underneath so I can't use `SUMIFS` if I don't have a value underneath the `RptLOB` column to give me those amounts.  I basically want it to include Disability and all other RptLOBs twice if there are two data values (GEP and NEP) or 12 times (if I have 12 columns with data)...if that makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you remove the first two lines?

Comment: @fabiopagoti  I could do that and then work off the pivot table.  I was hoping there would be another way so I wouldn't have to use a pivot table and just get the values from the file and insert them in my other file.

Comment: I'd handle the data (moving, coping etc) with VBA then, not necessarily using Pivot tables.

Comment: @fabiopagoti That's what I'm trying to do...I wasn't sure if I needed to code the pivot tables and extract data that way or if that was just not necessary.  I'm new with VBA coding so not quite sure what the best way to handle things, even with VBA would be...that's all.

Comment: @KristinaKotonika I see. Sorry for that. Considering you're new to VBA don't go for the Pivot table approach. Try recording a macro which copies, selects and paste values. In this scenario you have you will learn how to use things like Selection, Range, Cells, variables and logic control. See this to help recording a macro http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-how-to-excel-macro-recorder.html

Comment: @fabiopagoti  I've just recently learned the selection and copying, but in this case it's not a matter of copy and paste (I wish, it would make my life so easy haha).  I could have 12 columns with data with Disability being mentioned 30 times in the "NO NAME" column.  What I want then in my new file, is to have Disability mentioned only 12 times in the RptLOB column, for each data column (NEP, GEP, ...so on  and these are the values in my ECMAccount column).  Then, the Amount column is simply the sum of the GEP value (or NEP, or whatever my other 10 columns may be) for Disability, MSL, etc.

Comment: @KristinaKotonika Have you tried using WorkSheetFunctions?

Comment: Are the source files all Excel files?  And are you collecting all the contents into a single file, or summarizing each file individually?  Is there a fixed list of values which might be found in "No name", or are you only interested in certain values?

Comment: @TimWilliams All the files are excel files.What I want to do is once the math is done for one file,import that data in the file with the `RptLOB ECMAccount Amount` columns.Then move on to the next file and import the data underneath the first import and so on for all of my files.The "No Name" column right now has 46 distinct  names(which may later change)but they can be mentioned numerous times.I can have MSL mentioned twice w/ 2 GEP and NEP values or I can have it mentioned 10 times but in my final workbook,I want it to be mentioned twice (GEP,NEP) or 12 times (if I have 12 columns of data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I went overboard here, but it was such a fun challenge :)

Basically, you select the sheet you need to export and then run ExportData().

The way it works is:

1. Delete those first two empty rows in the source data
2. Sort the data by "NO NAME" - this makes it easier to sum up GEP/NEP
3. Go through the list and create an array of a User Defined Type (which has all the info we need on a per "NO NAME" basis) and sum up the values as necessary
4. Create a new workbook and export the data to there by iterating through the array

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum SourceColumns
    OperatingUnit = 1
    NoName
    GEP
    NEP
End Enum

Public Enum DestinationColumns
    rptLob = 1
    ECMAccount
    Amount
End Enum

Public Type rptLob
    Name As String
    GEP As Long
    NEP As Long
End Type

Public Sub ExportData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rptLobs() As rptLob

    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Call removeTwoRows(sh)
    Call sortNoNameColumn(sh)

    rptLobs = getRptLOBs(sh)

    Call exportToNewWorkbook(rptLobs)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub removeTwoRows(ByRef sh As Excel.Worksheet)
    sh.Rows("2:3").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Private Sub sortNoNameColumn(ByRef sh As Excel.Worksheet)
    sh.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    With sh.AutoFilter
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Cells(1, SourceColumns.NoName) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Private Function getRptLOBs(ByRef sh As Excel.Worksheet) As rptLob()
    Dim rptLobs() As rptLob
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim curRptLOB As Long

    lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 2

    Dim firstRptLOB As rptLob

    ' set first values
    firstRptLOB.Name = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NoName).Value
    firstRptLOB.GEP = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.GEP).Value
    firstRptLOB.NEP = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NEP).Value

    ReDim rptLobs(0)
    rptLobs(curRptLOB) = firstRptLOB

    For i = 3 To lastRow
        If (sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NoName).Value <> rptLobs(curRptLOB).Name) Then
            ' get a new rptLOB
            Dim newRptLOB As rptLob

            ' set first values
            newRptLOB.Name = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NoName).Value
            newRptLOB.GEP = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.GEP).Value
            newRptLOB.NEP = sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NEP).Value

            curRptLOB = curRptLOB + 1
            ReDim Preserve rptLobs(curRptLOB)

            rptLobs(curRptLOB) = newRptLOB
        Else
            ' add data to it
            rptLobs(curRptLOB).GEP = rptLobs(curRptLOB).GEP + sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.GEP).Value
            rptLobs(curRptLOB).NEP = rptLobs(curRptLOB).NEP + sh.Cells(i, SourceColumns.NEP).Value
        End If
    Next

    getRptLOBs = rptLobs
End Function

Private Sub exportToNewWorkbook(ByRef rptLobs() As rptLob)
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim index As Long
    Dim curRow As Long

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)

    ' Create Headers
    sh.Cells(1, DestinationColumns.rptLob).Value = "RptLOB"
    sh.Cells(1, DestinationColumns.ECMAccount).Value = "ECMAccount"
    sh.Cells(1, DestinationColumns.Amount).Value = "Amount"

    ' fill data
    For curRow = 2 To (UBound(rptLobs) + 1) * 2 + 1 Step 2 ' <-- double the amount of RptLOBs for GEP/NEP
        sh.Cells(curRow, DestinationColumns.rptLob).Value = rptLobs(index).Name
        sh.Cells(curRow, DestinationColumns.ECMAccount).Value = "GEP"
        sh.Cells(curRow, DestinationColumns.Amount).Value = rptLobs(index).GEP

        sh.Cells(curRow + 1, DestinationColumns.rptLob).Value = rptLobs(index).Name
        sh.Cells(curRow + 1, DestinationColumns.ECMAccount).Value = "NEP"
        sh.Cells(curRow + 1, DestinationColumns.Amount).Value = rptLobs(index).NEP

        index = index + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: oh wow. I'm glad you accepted the challenge! Thank you so much! I will definitely try it out!